# Poetry fail to find package while pip can

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I was trying to install the package [google-cloud-aiplatform](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-aiplatform/). I have the following lines in my `pyproject.toml` file

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]

google-cloud-aiplatform = "^1.28"
```

However, running `poetry install` I got the error

```
Because my_package depends on google-cloud-aiplatform (^1.28) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
```

I don't know how to fix the issue, pip can install the package with no issues.

**UPDATE**

I solved the issue by deleting the lock file and run `poetry install` again. After further investigating, I found that the correct workflow to add a new dependency to your poetry project is

1. use `poetry add [new_deps]`
2. run `poetry install` again.

I had this issue because I manually edited the `pyproject.toml` file. I still think this is a bug on the poetry side, the tool should allow user to edit config file. A perfect example would be Cargo for Rust.

Comment: You might be using two different Python versions with `pip` and `poetry`. `google-cloud-aiplatform 1.28` requires Python 3.7 to 3.10.

Comment: No that's not the case, both poetry and pip uses the same python3.9.

Comment: If you manually edit the `pyproject.toml` Poetry will warn you on install, that the lock file and the toml file are out of sync and suggests, than you should run `poetry lock --no-update`.

Comment: Yes that was what happened, I got the warning. However, I think poetry should not fail the installation in such cases.